# Missing dependency for UmlPTestErrorHandler

Tags: ivy

I have a [MontiCore](http://www.monticore.de) Project with the following defined dependencies in my ivy.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency name="de.monticore.re" rev="[2.0.5,2.0.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.monticore.ets" rev="[2.0.5,2.0.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.monticore.gli" rev="[2.0.5,2.0.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.umlp.umlpcore.fe" rev="[1.5.5,1.5.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.umlp.cd.fe" rev="[1.5.5,1.5.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.umlp.cdjava.fe" rev="[1.5.5,1.5.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.monticore.freemarker" rev="[2.0.5,2.0.5]" changing="false" />
  <dependency name="de.monticore.java" rev="[2.0.5,2.0.5]" changing="false" />
</dependencies>
```

I also use the UMLP class diagram language.

Eclipse is complaining that there is no mc.umlp.helpers.UmlPTestErrorHandler.

```
UmlPTestErrorHandler cannot be resolved AbstractCoCoTest.java   /MontiWIS/test/integration/de/montiwis/tool line 31 Java Problem
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you have a customized ivy setup. Without the ivysettings.xml file there is no possibility of troubleshooting this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UmlPTestErrorHandler no longer exists since version 1.5.4. It was replaced by mc.test.helpers.TestErrorHandler (de.monticore.gli). Use this class.

Comment: Switching to the new class fixed the problem.